# How to prove a trefoil is not an unknot not using the theorem of Reidemeister moves

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

Let me ask how to prove that the trefoil class is not a sub class of the unknot class, not using the theorem of Reidemeister moves.

The reason to exclude the theorem of Reidemeister moves is I have read in the following link that the complete proof is not easily accessible.
[Link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15217/proof-of-the-reidemeister-theorem)

Comment: The trefoil is 3-colourable, and the unknot is *not* 3-colourable. However, to check that Three-colourability is a knot-invariant, one would like to use Reidemeister moves. The knot group of the unknot is $\mathbb{Z}$, in contrast to the trefoil.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thank you very much. Do both invariants have proofs not using the theorem?

Comment: Yes, see the proof [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjs45b497XLAhXMXhoKHWzeCSUQFggiMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.uchicago.edu%2F~may%2FREU2014%2FREUPapers%2FLinov.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEOUEserQwVmKnaTyfkN3ZgM414ew&sig2=6B9ixvTtrts-DBL47cIfJw), Proposition $2.2$.